# How do I use fbr files?

Tags: video, proprietary

I have a video file in fbr format. These files are supported in BB Flash Back Express. I want to install that in my ubuntu, but couldn't find any way. Is there any way to install flash back player in Ubuntu ?

**Specs:**

- OS: Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the only supported solution to play back recordings made with that software is to export to another format, because known players like VLC Media Player and MPlayer don't support the format due to it's proprietary nature and lack of support from the manufacturer to provide a Linux version or documentation on how to decode the format.

If someone sends you `.fbr` files, kindly ask them convert them into `.m4v`/`.mp4` or even better `.webm`.

> BB FlashBack stores its movies in FlashBack (FBR) format. If you want
>   non-FlashBack users to be able to watch your movie, you'll need to
>   export it to a standard format. BB FlashBack exports to QuickTime,
>   Flash, **MPEG4**, AVI, Windows Media Video (WMV), and Executable (EXE).

Source: [BB FlashBack FAQ](http://www.bbsoftware.co.uk/BBFlashBack/FAQ.aspx)

> Exporting to executable format is the worst thing, don't do that.

Answer (score -2):

Flash Back Player is installable via wine. Type these commands in a Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Then, download Flash Back Player, right click it, and select open with Wine Windows Program Loader. Run through the installation like you would in Windows and it should work.